# How to save state of selenium web driver in python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape this website: http://www.infoempleo.com/ofertas-internacionales/.
I wanted to scrape by selecting the "Last 15 days" radio button. So I wrote this code.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Users\Junaid\Downloads\chromedriver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
new_urls = deque(['http://www.infoempleo.com/ofertas-internacionales/'])

processed_urls = set()

while len(new_urls):

print "------ URL LIST -------"
print new_urls
print "-----------------------"
print
time.sleep(5)

url = new_urls.popleft()
processed_urls.add(url)

try:
    print "----------- Scraping ==>",url
    browser.get(url)
    elem = browser.find_elements_by_id("fechapublicacion")[-1]
    if ( elem.is_selected() ):
        print "already selected"
    else:
        elem.click()

    html = browser.page_source
except:
    print "-------- Failed to Scrape, Moving to Next"
    continue

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

I have been able to select the radio button and scrape the first page.
There is a list of pages at the end like 1, 2, 3..

When moving to the next page, `'browser.get(url)'` is called which resets the radio button to 'Any Date' instead of 'Last 15 Days'. Which makes the code execute the else statement `else: elem.click()` to select the radio button again, which open the first page that has been already scraped.

Is there a way around this? Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around this problem. Instead of saving links to next pages in a list. I am selecting the nextPage button/element and using `.click()`. This way the `browser.get(url)` is not needed to call again and the page is not reloaded.